# Using log4j 2.10.0 with Java 9 System.Logger

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, java-9

How do I setup Java 9 so that `System.Logger` instances write to log4j 2.10.0, instead of writing to JUL?

Comment: As far as I know, there are no log4j bindings for `System.Logger` yet. You have to write a service provider manually.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov The [log4j 2.9 release notes](https://blogs.apache.org/logging/entry/log4j-2-9-released) mention that `java.util.ServiceLoader` can now locate log4j, and [`java.lang.System.LoggerFinder` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.LoggerFinder.html) say that `java.util.ServiceLoader` loads the logging implementation…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the paragraph you refer to:

> This release contains the first support of Java 9 as well as bugfixes and minor enhancements. The Log4j API was modified to use `java.util.ServiceLoader` to locate Log4j implementations, although the former binding mechanism is still supported. The Log4j jar is now a multi-release jar to provide implementations of the Java 9 specific classes.

It doesn't mention `System.LoggerFinder` and indeed a full-text search of [the repo](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/source-repository.html) (of version 2.10) didn't turn up any mention of "LoggerFinder" and nothing promising for "java.lang.System". I'm hence sure that Log4J 2.10 does not yet integrate with [JEP 264: Platform Logging API and Service](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/264).

What the release notes seem to refer to instead is that Log4J now uses the `ServiceLoader` API when looking for implementations of *its own* API.

### Do it yourself

If you really need/want Log4J to log these messages, you can roll your own adapter [as I did here for SLF4J](https://github.com/nicolaiparlog/slf4j/commit/e0c7780bdae254535a6e9c053b2af564085ffe3b). All you need are Log4J adapters for `System.Logger` and `System.LoggerFinder` (both straightforward to implement if you skimp on some of the details) and either a `META-INF/services` file or a module declaration like the following:

```
module org.slf4j.platform {
    // put the right module name here
    requires log4j;
    provides java.lang.System.LoggerFinder
        // put the right class name here
        with org.log4J.Log4JSystemLoggerFinder;
}
```

Launching your application with that artifact will then lead to Log4J getting platform log messages.

Comment: Nicolai, your analysis is correct. Log4j2 doesn’t integrate yet with JEP 264. This should be added to the roadmap. Would you min raising this as a feature request on the Log4j2 JIRA issue tracker?

Comment: Turns out, [there has been one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1360) since April 2016. 

Comment: @Nicolai Did you consider to push this upstream to SLF4J?

Comment: I subscribed to the mailing list in January and then... did nothing. I took your comment as inspiration to finally [send a proposal](http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/slf4j-dev/2018-August/005038.html). Thanks. 

Answer (score 6):

Log4j 2 supports JDK platform logging [since version 2.13.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1360). If you want to use `System.Logger` with Log4j 2 as a backend, you need to use `log4j-jpl` adapter:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${replace.with.right.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>${replace.with.right.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jpl</artifactId>
    <version>${replace.with.right.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

After that, your `System.Logger` will redirect logs to Log4j:

```
public final class Main {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = System.getLogger("");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.ERROR, "Hello, {}!", "user");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
11:02:44.736 [main] ERROR  - Hello, user!
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted by the question owner. This is the right way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use Log4j2’s [Java util logging adapter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jul/index.html) to route all JUL logging to Log4j2?

To enable this, set system property `java.util.logging.manager` to `org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager` and add `log4j-jul` to your dependencies.